# Hedera transfer token between accounts - recipent paying transaction fees

Tags: hedera-hashgraph

I want to transfer tokens (fungible) from account A to account B, but I want the transaction to be submitted by account B and consequently account B pays the transaction fees.
Is this possible in Hedera?

Comment: I know this is not possible in EVM because the transaction model does not allow for it, as the payer account must be the submitter account. Any solution attempting to do this requires complex workaround such as account abstraction.

Comment: But on Hedera, the payer account and the submitter account are allowed to be 2 separate accounts, so this should be possible. It won't be possible using JSON-RPC, AFAIK, since that needs to comply with the EVM transaction standard ... therefore if possible, you'd need to do so using the Hedera SDK. Let me confirm the above, and find out how.